# Getting the number of satellites from Location object

Tags: android, gps, location, satellite

I'm using a GPS provider and LocationListener.onLocationChanged(Location location) to receive location fixes.
[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getExtras%28%29) says, that Location.getExtras() contains next key/value pair:

> satellites - the number of satellites used to derive the fix

but on practice I'm getting an empty extra object - there is no any data there.
Does it means that I'm getting the A-GPS fixes and not GPS?

Answer (score 21):

To get the number of satellites used by the GPS engine you need to implement `android.location.GpsStatus.Listener` and implement its method `onGpsStatusChanged()`.

Example...

```
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
    int satellites = 0;
    int satellitesInFix = 0;
    int timetofix = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null).getTimeToFirstFix();
    Log.i(TAG, "Time to first fix = " + timetofix);
    for (GpsSatellite sat : locationManager.getGpsStatus(null).getSatellites()) {
        if(sat.usedInFix()) {
            satellitesInFix++;              
        }
        satellites++;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, satellites + " Used In Last Fix ("+satellitesInFix+")"); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why I need to implement a listener if I want to poll for the number of satellites... yet trying to call getSatellites() without setting up a listener always returns no satellites, even when a GPS has a fix and is locked.

Comment: It's very important to add the listener to the location manager like locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(<whatever implemented GpsStatus.Listener>); or else the listener won't be called.

Answer (score 14):

I use Location.getExtras().getInt("satellites"), and it give the number of satellites in use.

Answer (score 6):

Since Android API 24 `GpsStatus` is deprecated and one should use `GnssStatus`. Let us have an activity or a service processing Gps data and a `LocationManager` already created.

```
private GnssStatus.Callback gnssCallback;

public void initCallbacks() {
    ....
    gnssCallback = new GnssStatus.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSatelliteStatusChanged(@NonNull GnssStatus status) {
            final int satelliteCount = status.getSatelliteCount();
            int usedCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < satelliteCount; ++i)
                if (status.usedInFix(i))
                    ++usedCount;
            Log.d("MyServiceTag", "satellites count = " + satelliteCount + ", used = " + usedCount);
        }
    };
    locationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(gnssCallback, new Handler(Looper.myLooper()));
    ....
}

public void deinitCallbacks() {
    ....
    locationManager.unregisterGnssStatusCallback(gnssCallback);
    ....
}
```

`initCallbacks()` should be called after `locationManager` initialization. `deinitCallbacks()` should be called when information on the number of satellites is no longer needed, e.g. in `onDestroy()`.  `GnssStatus.getSatelliteCount()` returns total number of known satellites, `GnssStatus.usedInFix(int i)` tells whether i-th satellite had been used in the most actual location capture.

Answer (score 1):

Nope it means that your phone manufacturer decided not to implement this. (Or you could be using the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` which does not use satellites)

Use a [`NmeaListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html) and parse the sentences to know the number of satellites visible or used.

Comment: I'm definitely using GPS_PROVIDER. There is a chance that Samsung din't implemented this in Nexus S?

Comment: You should be able to get it using [bundle.getInt("satellites")](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getInt(java.lang.String). Are you sure you're getting fixes? Use the Nmea listener and look at the [GPGSV sentences](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm)

Comment: You right, Location.getExtras().getInt("satellites") suppose to return the number of satellites. But its not - I'm always getting a zero there despite the fact that location object itself contains a valid coordinates