# Android GPS : Why the number of satellites in use is so high?

Tags: android, gps, nmea

I use Nmea string for find satellites in use. (7th instance of GPGGA). but it shows satellite numbers like 10-11 even 12. but the coordinate that I get is not accurate...
I used location.getextra . but this one like NMEA show many satellites... my android GPS use 10 satellites?(then why my coordinate is not accurate?) or just see them?

Comment: You should see this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580603/getting-the-number-of-satellites-from-location-object

Comment: What do you understand under "not accurate"? How many meters is the reported location of the real one? And in which country? Many countries dont have an GPS correction system,  like US WAAS and Europe EGNOS. So accurcay can be 3m in Europe/US and 6m in parts of Asia

Comment: thank u @bhuvesh... I got the number of sats by getExtra and NMEA.

Comment: @AlexWien thank u so much. I'm from asia... how can I see correction system's place? I mean the numbers of lat and long don't show a fix number and are changed continusely... when I was in a middle of city that has tall buildings it show the count of sats 10 .. and the lat and long change like this ==> xx.xxx---- (x is fix character and '-' changes nonstop) and when I'm not in someWhere like parks ... it change like this ==> xx.xxxxx---  ....... I mean in the fist situation if GPS uses 10 sats it should show me the lat and long like this: xx.xxxx---

Comment: @AlexWien sorry about my poor English.. if I coudln't explain clearly ..tell me .. I'll try to say it better .. thank u again.

Comment: Again the simple question: How many meters are your positions wrong?3m,6m, 10m, 30m, or 50m?

Comment: ok. I'm going to check it .